# "Instance member 'pickImage' can't be accessed using static access." error in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-image-picker

I have ran into a problem concerning my Flutter app , to use select picture from gallery in Flutter and `pickImage` is underlined and had this "`Instance member 'pickImage' can't be accessed using static access`." error. How to fix this error.

This is my code

```
class _CreateBlogState extends State<CreateBlog> {
  late String authorName, title, description;
  late File selectedImage;

  BlogCrudMethods blogCrudMethods = new BlogCrudMethods();


  Future getImage() async {
    var image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);

    setState(() {
      selectedImage = image as File;
    });
  }
```

[image]

Comment: please visit https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73299004/instance-member-pickimage-cant-be-accessed-using-static-acce

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a `ImagePicker` instance to use `pickImage` while it is not static method.

```dart
await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
```